# Sorting issues for Xcode tableview

Tags: xcode, uitableview

So I have a uitableview set up that downloads data from mysql. I'm trying to get my app so that the most viewed movies appear at the top of the table, but although this way puts the 0 views at the bottom, it actually then flips those so that the most viewed is at the bottom of the non-0 viewed cells. Apparently, xcode keeps telling me that there is no descending command. How do I fix something like this?

```
sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"viewers" ascending:NO];
[beaus sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]]; //beaus is a NSMutableArray
```

Comment: What type is the item you are sorting on? NSSNumber, NSString, something else?

Answer (score 0):

You're not instantiating the `NSSortDescriptor` properly.

```
sortDesc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"viewers" ascending:YES];
```

Then simply set your `sortDescriptor` to a `sortDescriptors` `NSArray`.

Comment: I can't get that working jsksma2. How did you set it up to an NSArray?

Comment: Try: `sortDesc = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"viewers" ascending:YES]];`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"viewers" ascending:NO];
[beaus sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDesc]];
```

This assumes that the value being compares compare in the desired order, Comparing numbers expressed as `NSString`s is many times problematic,

Comment: Please show the items you are comparing and their types. Without example data we are just guessing.